# Meaning of "to lie in the kernel/support" with reference to linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some clarifications about a couple of statements that I found in a paper and I cannot clearly understand, related to linear operators.

$S$ is an Hermitian operator.
$S^\perp$ is orthogonal complement of S.
$R$ is another Hermitian operator.

What does it mean the following statement? $S^\perp$ lies in the kernel of $S$

And what does it mean the following one? $S$ and $S^\perp$ lie in the support of $R$

Comment: I am puzzled by how the heck could operator have orthogonal complement... I mean "orthogonal complement" can only refer to subspace of a linear space....

Comment: Yes. It seems that something got confused here. Please link to the paper.

Comment: Here is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10863